# Install software using powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to install Notepad++ software using a PowerShell v2.0 script for one of my POC. I need to install the client's software in my current project. As I am running the below script I'm getting errors.

```
Start-Process 'C:\Users\kirnen\Desktop\A\npp.7.5.Installer.exe'-InstallerParameters "/S" `
-RegistryKey HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Notepad++ `
-RegistryName DisplayVersion -RegistryValue 7.5
```

As I am very much new to powershell scripting, can you please help in this? Is the above code right, or do I need to change anything else to install the software?

Comment: There is no parameter like -RegistryKey or InstallerParameters for Start-process. The Notepad exe should write such regkeys. Try google to find how to install an exe with powershell

Comment: can you help in this. wat I need to do..??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this snippet of PowerShell code for a lot of installs. As long as you can figure out the silent switch for ".exe's". For ".msi's" just change out where `Create()` with `Create("msiexec /I C:\temp\generic.msi /qn")`

```
$computers = c:\temp\computerName.csv
$Notepad = "Location of notepad install"

$computers | where{test-connection $_ -quiet -count 1} | ForEach-Object {

  copy-item $Notepad -recurse "\\$_\c$\temp" 

  $newProc=([WMICLASS]"\\$_\root\cimv2:win32_Process").Create("C:\temp\npp.6.9.2.Installer.exe /S")

  If ($newProc.ReturnValue -eq 0) { 
    Write-Host $_ $newProc.ProcessId 
  } else { 
    write-host $_ Process create failed with $newProc.ReturnValue 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few different ways to do this. The way you're doing it is fine, but I don't think you really want all those install parameters.

`Start-Process 'C:\Users\kirnen\Desktop\A\npp.7.5.Installer.exe' "/S"`

The `/S` part means you want a silent install, so you won't see an install wizard, and won't be able to choose any options. Not a bad thing, just be sure that's what you want. Take off the `"/S"` if you want to follow the graphical install wizard.

Instead of `Start-Process` you can also use `cmd /c` and just `&`. These have their advantages and disadvantages. Stick with `Start-Process` for now.

One last thing, with many .exe files you can follow them with `/help` or `/?` to get a list of their command line switches.

Answer (score 2):

#Install Chocolatey Provider

```
Get-Package -Provider chocolatey -Force
```

#Install Software

```
Install-Package adobereader, 7zip, anydesk, firefox, notepadplusplus, teamviewer, vlc -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a Powershell script with Chocolatey to perform the installation of programs from a list in json.

It will install chocolatey, check the packages, and them install then

Take a look in the repo: https://github.com/SandimL/Powershell-automatic-installation

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Winget utility

Do Winget search "YourPackage" on cmd or powershell terminal
and take what package you want and do "Winget install YourPackage"
Like this for example i want to install chrome :

```
Winget install Google.Chrome
```